# Oracle Enterprise Edition for Eclipse Indigo Error: failed to connect remote VM .connection refused

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, eclipse-indigo

I am using Oracle Enterprise Edition for Eclipse Indigo machine with Oracle Web Logic Server 12.1.1. When I try to run a simple RESTful web service demo by starting the WLS in debugging mode it shows the error

> "failed to connect to remote VM. connection refused."

What could be the cause of this error?  How it can be resolved?